# Roaming through AP lose contact with part of the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, dhcp

I hope you can help me with a problem bothering me for long now.

I have a small home network with two routers. Both broadcast a same SSID, **router/modem "1**" in channel 6, **router "2"** in channel 1 (see network map below). The problem starts when I roam through wifi with a gadget. As you can see, I have devices connected in both routers. If I connect in router "2" wireless for example, and move to router "1", I lose network access to anything connected to router "2". The opposite apparently do not occur. The only way of solving is restarting router "2"

- **Router "1"** provides access to internet, the local IP is 192.168.25.1, DHCP is **on**. There is reserved IP's for router "2" and the media server.
- **Router "2"** have the IP 192.168.25.2, DHCP and NAT are **off**.
- **Media Server** have a static IP reserved in **router "1"**

The one and only solution I find for this problem is having two completely separated wireless signals, different SSID, but that solution is unwanted since I move a lot through the house. When using the same SSID, the roaming mechanism works just fine, I can get from bedroom to living room and the access point changing works very well but, as I said I lost contact with the bedroom router "2".

The problem happens with every wireless device on the house.

I feel like I'm doing a simple mistake, but I can't see what is really the problem. I hope one of you can help me out of this.

[Network map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AkwX.png)

Comment: How are the two routers connected to each other? If by wire, is it LAN-to-LAN or LAN-to-WAN? Is it direct or through a switch?

Comment: LAN-to-LAN, directly.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing everything right. It could be a router setting, or maybe your router 2 just has a poor bridging implementation (possibly in its Wifi hardware) and doesn't notice that the MAC address isn't attached to its Wifi anymore.

Comment: I feared that could be a problem, a good router here in Brazil cost a full month of work... Any chance a firmware update may fix that issue, if it is in fact the router?

I just noticed that the LAN and the 5Ghz have the same MAC address in router 2. Wireless 2.4GHz and WAN have different MAC. Is that normal?

Comment: I found a 'interface emulator' of the Router 2, if would be useful.

http://www.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/wdr4300/index.htm

Comment: Replace the firmware with DD-WRT ?

Comment: Wow, never heard of that before, googled it and it looks interesting. I'm not an advanced user, could I operate a firmware like that? Any chance that would solve the issue?

I looked in the site and my router is supported. Should I make the upgrade?

Comment: And I apologize for the misuse of the word "router". Guess that made things quite confusing.

Comment: It's possible that it's a firmware issue and replacing the firmware with DD-WRT could help. I generally replace every router firmware with DD-WRT, Tomato, OpenWRT, or some other open source firmware because I was tired of having to deal with every proprietary firmware's weird quirks.

Comment: If I can't handle the new firmware, it is possible to "downgrade"? I know nothing about coding/programming.

Comment: Would be needed an "firmware killer" before the WRT upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that the firmware in one of your routers (it could be either one, really) is crappy and isn't updating its bridge table correctly when the MAC address of the client moves from being on that router's wireless interface to being seen on its Ethernet LAN interface (or vice-versa).

It's *probably* router 2 that's at fault, but rebooting it also cycles the Ethernet link for router 1, so it's still possible that router 1 is at fault, but cycling the Ethernet link clears up the problem (unless you've already found that unplugging and re-plugging that cable doesn't get it out of the bad state).

Sometimes you can help bridges (I use the term "bridges" in the expansive sense of anything that provides 802.1D bridge-like functionality, including switches and the integrated LAN/WLAN parts of home gateways and APs) update their bridge tables faster by sending multicasts or broadcasts from the MAC address of the device that moved. This usually occurs automatically due to ARP and DHCP broadcasts, but if you want to try forcing it by sending your own broadcasts/multicasts from the device seeing the issue, you could try pinging some broadcast and multicast addresses, such as 192.168.25.255 (assuming you're using a /24 subnet), 255.255.255.255, and 224.0.0.1, from the device that has lost touch with the other half of the network.

Aftermarket open-source router firmware distros might be less likely to have this bug, so updating your routers to OpenWrt/DD-WRT/Tomato/Gargoyle/etc. might clear this up for you.

Comment: DD-WRT update solve it! The problem roaming between the two wireless AP is gone, but the connection between the two routers is unstable. If I ping router 1 connected from router 2, it fails every two or three shots...

Any idea? I followed the DD-WRT guides of configuration.

Comment: Should I solve this question and start another one?

Comment: @J.Grimm Yes, a separate Question seems warranted.